# How can I enable on-off toggle with bootstrap on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement this on-off toggle on my rails app.
http://www.larentis.eu/bootstrap_toggle_buttons/
https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch

So, what I have done is,

creating these below

- /assets/javascripts/bootstrap_toggle.js
- /assets/javascripts/toggle.js
- /assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_toggle.css.erb

In **views/layouts/application.html.erb**  I've added these

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap_toggle.js' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrap_toggle' %>
```

Then I've added this to view to show **toggle**

```
<div id="normal-toggle-button">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</div>
```

after everything above, I executed

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

However, it only shows regular check-box, not the toggle :( 
Why? and how can I fix???

**/assets/javascripts/bootstrap_toggle.js**

```
!function ($) {
  "use strict";

  $.fn['bootstrapSwitch'] = function (method) {
    var methods = {
      init: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $element = $(this)
              , $div
              , $switchLeft
              , $switchRight
              , $label
              , myClasses = ""
              , classes = $element.attr('class')
              , color
              , moving
              , onLabel = "ON"
              , offLabel = "OFF"
              , icon = false;

            $.each(['switch-mini', 'switch-small', 'switch-large'], function (i, el) {
              if (classes.indexOf(el) >= 0)
                myClasses = el;
            });

            $element.addClass('has-switch');

            if ($element.data('on') !== undefined)
              color = "switch-" + $element.data('on');

            if ($element.data('on-label') !== undefined)
              onLabel = $element.data('on-label');

            if ($element.data('off-label') !== undefined)
              offLabel = $element.data('off-label');

            if ($element.data('icon') !== undefined)
              icon = $element.data('icon');

            $switchLeft = $('<span>')
              .addClass("switch-left")
              .addClass(myClasses)
              .addClass(color)
              .html(onLabel);

            color = '';
            if ($element.data('off') !== undefined)
              color = "switch-" + $element.data('off');

            $switchRight = $('<span>')
              .addClass("switch-right")
              .addClass(myClasses)
              .addClass(color)
              .html(offLabel);

            $label = $('<label>')
              .html("&nbsp;")
              .addClass(myClasses)
              .attr('for', $element.find('input').attr('id'));

            if (icon) {
              $label.html('<i class="icon icon-' + icon + '"></i>');
            }

            $div = $element.find(':checkbox').wrap($('<div>')).parent().data('animated', false);

            if ($element.data('animated') !== false)
              $div.addClass('switch-animate').data('animated', true);

            $div
              .append($switchLeft)
              .append($label)
              .append($switchRight);

            $element.find('>div').addClass(
              $element.find('input').is(':checked') ? 'switch-on' : 'switch-off'
            );

            if ($element.find('input').is(':disabled'))
              $(this).addClass('deactivate');

            var changeStatus = function ($this) {
              $this.siblings('label').trigger('mousedown').trigger('mouseup').trigger('click');
            };

            $element.on('keydown', function (e) {
              if (e.keyCode === 32) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                changeStatus($(e.target).find('span:first'));
              }
            });

            $switchLeft.on('click', function (e) {
              changeStatus($(this));
            });

            $switchRight.on('click', function (e) {
              changeStatus($(this));
            });

            $element.find('input').on('change', function (e) {
              var $this = $(this)
                , $element = $this.parent()
                , thisState = $this.is(':checked')
                , state = $element.is('.switch-off');

              e.preventDefault();

              $element.css('left', '');

              if (state === thisState) {

                if (thisState)
                  $element.removeClass('switch-off').addClass('switch-on');
                else $element.removeClass('switch-on').addClass('switch-off');

                if ($element.data('animated') !== false)
                  $element.addClass("switch-animate");

                $element.parent().trigger('switch-change', {'el': $this, 'value': thisState})
              }
            });

            $element.find('label').on('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
              var $this = $(this);
              moving = false;

              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopImmediatePropagation();

              $this.closest('div').removeClass('switch-animate');

              if ($this.closest('.switch').is('.deactivate'))
                $this.unbind('click');
              else {
                $this.on('mousemove touchmove', function (e) {
                  var $element = $(this).closest('.switch')
                    , relativeX = (e.pageX || e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX) - $element.offset().left
                    , percent = (relativeX / $element.width()) * 100
                    , left = 25
                    , right = 75;

                  moving = true;

                  if (percent < left)
                    percent = left;
                  else if (percent > right)
                    percent = right;

                  $element.find('>div').css('left', (percent - right) + "%")
                });

                $this.on('click touchend', function (e) {
                  var $this = $(this)
                    , $target = $(e.target)
                    , $myCheckBox = $target.siblings('input');

                  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                  e.preventDefault();

                  $this.unbind('mouseleave');

                  if (moving)
                    $myCheckBox.prop('checked', !(parseInt($this.parent().css('left')) < -25));
                  else $myCheckBox.prop("checked", !$myCheckBox.is(":checked"));

                  moving = false;
                  $myCheckBox.trigger('change');
                });

                $this.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
                  var $this = $(this)
                    , $myCheckBox = $this.siblings('input');

                  e.preventDefault();
                  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                  $this.unbind('mouseleave');
                  $this.trigger('mouseup');

                  $myCheckBox.prop('checked', !(parseInt($this.parent().css('left')) < -25)).trigger('change');
                });

                $this.on('mouseup', function (e) {
                  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                  e.preventDefault();

                  $(this).unbind('mousemove');
                });
              }
            });
          }
        );
      },
      toggleActivation: function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('deactivate');
      },
      isActive: function () {
        return !$(this).hasClass('deactivate');
      },
      setActive: function (active) {
        if (active)
          $(this).removeClass('deactivate');
        else $(this).addClass('deactivate');
      },
      toggleState: function (skipOnChange) {
        var $input = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
        $input.prop('checked', !$input.is(':checked')).trigger('change', skipOnChange);
      },
      setState: function (value, skipOnChange) {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', value).trigger('change', skipOnChange);
      },
      status: function () {
        return $(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked');
      },
      destroy: function () {
        var $div = $(this).find('div')
          , $checkbox;

        $div.find(':not(input:checkbox)').remove();

        $checkbox = $div.children();
        $checkbox.unwrap().unwrap();

        $checkbox.unbind('change');

        return $checkbox;
      }
    };

    if (methods[method])
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method)
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    else
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist!');
  };
}(jQuery);

$(function () {
  $('.switch')['bootstrapSwitch']();
});
```

**/assets/javascripts/toggle.js**

```
$('#normal-toggle-button').toggleButtons();
```

**/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_toggle.css.erb**

```
.has-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 8px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.has-switch.switch-mini {
  min-width: 72px;
}
.has-switch.switch-small {
  min-width: 80px;
}
.has-switch.switch-large {
  min-width: 120px;
}
.has-switch.deactivate {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  cursor: default !important;
}
.has-switch.deactivate label,
.has-switch.deactivate span {
  cursor: default !important;
}
.has-switch > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.has-switch > div.switch-animate {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.5s;
  -o-transition: left 0.5s;
  transition: left 0.5s;
}
.has-switch > div.switch-off {
  left: -50%;
}
.has-switch > div.switch-on {
  left: 0%;
}
.has-switch input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.has-switch span,
.has-switch label {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.has-switch span.switch-mini,
.has-switch label.switch-mini {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 9px;
}
.has-switch span.switch-small,
.has-switch label.switch-small {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.has-switch span.switch-large,
.has-switch label.switch-large {
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: normal;
}
.has-switch label {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 34%;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.has-switch label:hover,
.has-switch label:focus,
.has-switch label:active,
.has-switch label.active,
.has-switch label.disabled,
.has-switch label[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  *background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.has-switch label:active,
.has-switch label.active {
  background-color: #cccccc \9;
}
.has-switch label i {
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  line-height: 18px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.has-switch span {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 33%;
}
.has-switch span.switch-left {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.has-switch span.switch-right {
  color: #333333;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6, #ffffff);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#e6e6e6), to(#ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6, #ffffff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e6e6e6, #ffffff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e6e6e6, #ffffff);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', endColorstr='#ffffffff', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #ffffff #ffffff #d9d9d9;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  *background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.has-switch span.switch-right:hover,
.has-switch span.switch-right:focus,
.has-switch span.switch-right:active,
.has-switch span.switch-right.active,
.has-switch span.switch-right.disabled,
.has-switch span.switch-right[disabled] {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  *background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.has-switch span.switch-right:active,
.has-switch span.switch-right.active {
  background-color: #e6e6e6 \9;
}
.has-switch span.switch-primary,
.has-switch span.switch-left {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #005fcc;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0044cc, #0088cc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0044cc), to(#0088cc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0044cc, #0088cc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0044cc, #0088cc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0044cc, #0088cc);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0044cc', endColorstr='#ff0088cc', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #0088cc #0088cc #005580;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  *background-color: #0088cc;
  /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.has-switch span.switch-primary:hover,
.has-switch span.switch-left:hover,
.has-switch span.switch-primary:focus,
.has-switch span.switch-left:focus,
.has-switch span.switch-primary:active,
.has-switch span.switch-left:active,
.has-switch span.switch-primary.active,
.has-switch span.switch-left.active,
.has-switch span.switch-primary.disabled,
.has-switch span.switch-left.disabled,
.has-switch span.switch-primary[disabled],
.has-switch span.switch-left[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0088cc;
  *background-color: #0077b3;
}
.has-switch span.switch-primary:active,
.has-switch span.switch-left:active,
.has-switch span.switch-primary.active,
.has-switch span.switch-left.active {
  background-color: #006699 \9;
}
.has-switch span.switch-info {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #41a7c5;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2f96b4, #5bc0de);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#2f96b4), to(#5bc0de));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f96b4, #5bc0de);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2f96b4, #5bc0de);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2f96b4, #5bc0de);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff2f96b4', endColorstr='#ff5bc0de', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #5bc0de #5bc0de #28a1c5;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  *background-color: #5bc0de;
  /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.has-switch span.switch-info:hover,
.has-switch span.switch-info:focus,
.has-switch span.switch-info:active,
.has-switch span.switch-info.active,
.has-switch span.switch-info.disabled,
.has-switch span.switch-info[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  *background-color: #46b8da;
}
.has-switch span.switch-info:active,
.has-switch span.switch-info.active {
  background-color: #31b0d5 \9;
}
.has-switch span.switch-success {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #58b058;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #51a351, #62c462);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#51a351), to(#62c462));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #51a351, #62c462);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #51a351, #62c462);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #51a351, #62c462);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff51a351', endColorstr='#ff62c462', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #62c462 #62c462 #3b9e3b;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  *background-color: #62c462;
  /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.has-switch span.switch-success:hover,
.has-switch span.switch-success:focus,
.has-switch span.switch-success:active,
.has-switch span.switch-success.active,
.has-switch span.switch-success.disabled,
.has-switch span.switch-success[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #62c462;
  *background-color: #4fbd4f;
}
.has-switch span.switch-success:active,
.has-switch span.switch-success.active {
  background-color: #42b142 \9;
}
.has-switch span.switch-warning {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #f9a123;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f89406, #fbb450);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f89406), to(#fbb450));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f89406, #fbb450);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f89406, #fbb450);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f89406, #fbb450);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff89406', endColorstr='#fffbb450', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #fbb450 #fbb450 #f89406;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  *background-color: #fbb450;
  /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.has-switch span.switch-warning:hover,
.has-switch span.switch-warning:focus,
.has-switch span.switch-warning:active,
.has-switch span.switch-warning.active,
.has-switch span.switch-warning.disabled,
.has-switch span.switch-warning[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fbb450;
  *background-color: #faa937;
}
.has-switch span.switch-warning:active,
.has-switch span.switch-warning.active {
  background-color: #fa9f1e \9;
}
.has-switch span.switch-danger {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #d14641;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bd362f, #ee5f5b);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#bd362f), to(#ee5f5b));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bd362f, #ee5f5b);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bd362f, #ee5f5b);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bd362f, #ee5f5b);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffbd362f', endColorstr='#ffee5f5b', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #ee5f5b #ee5f5b #e51d18;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  *background-color: #ee5f5b;
  /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.has-switch span.switch-danger:hover,
.has-switch span.switch-danger:focus,
.has-switch span.switch-danger:active,
.has-switch span.switch-danger.active,
.has-switch span.switch-danger.disabled,
.has-switch span.switch-danger[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ee5f5b;
  *background-color: #ec4844;
}
.has-switch span.switch-danger:active,
.has-switch span.switch-danger.active {
  background-color: #e9322d \9;
}
```

Comment: is regular `bootstrap` preventing it??

Comment: Did you figure this out?